# What is the word/ expression for 'when the content received via an information medium is transferred to another medium'?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

I have viewed [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/377827/is-there-a-word-or-phrase-to-describe-the-action-of-replying-to-communication-vi) but none of the answers quite match what I am looking for.

The German term for this word is 'Medienbruch'. The translated definition on the [corresponding wikipedia page](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medienbruch) is:

> A Medienbruch[*literally translated as 'media break'*] occurs in information processing when the content received via an information medium is transferred to another medium in the transmission chain of a process and has to be generated again.

One example would be having to print out a form filled out online to give to a different department.

An example usage could be:

> The online forms are processed on a centralized platform without any [word here]

Comment: "Transcription", perhaps?

Comment: 'Bottleneck' seems close (as a hypernym).

Comment: Your own question shows you are asking about transferring data without _regeneration_. No? Also, computer jargon calls it _sneakernet_ when you have to put on your running shoes to dash over the data from one format to another (really, any physical move that is not automated) instead of the darn computer handling the transfer directly.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest [*change of medium*](https://www.linguee.com/english-german/translation/change+of+medium.html).

Answer (score 1):

content is said to be repurposed or reconfigured:

> 1) "My article on 40 Ideas For Comedians To Think About was one of the
>   most successful (and easiest) posts [content] I’ve ever written and it simply
>   featured a bunch of **repurposed tweets** I had posted over the past few
>   years on my Connected Comedy Twitter account.
>
> 2) Recently the live stream content was **reconfigured** and chunk size
>   changed from 6 seconds to 2 seconds and I start receiving error 412
>   for loading the content chunks. Instructions that I have are that I
>   have to make the bufferingTime to 12 seconds and liveBackOff to 6
>   seconds."
>
> I tried different combination changing the BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE,
>   VIDEO_BUFFER_SEGMENTS and LIVE_EDGE_LATENCY_MS but nothing works.

[repurposed](http://connectedcomedy.com/repurpose-social-media-content/)

[reconfigured](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/1872)

http://connectedcomedy.com/repurpose-social-media-content/

Answer (score 1):

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/transcoding defines:

> **transcoding** noun [ U ]
>
> computing   specialized
>
> the process of changing computer information that is stored in a particular code (= a language used to program computers) into another code:
> *The software provides "transcoding" - translation between standard web pages written in standard HTML (Hypertext Markup Language) and Wap's WML (Wireless Markup Language).*

This feels the most correct term in this case. However my first thought was "port", which https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/port defines:

> **port** verb [ T ]
>
> IT, COMMUNICATIONS
>
> to move software, a phone number, etc. to another system, without it being changed:
>
> port sth to sth *Our staff will check if your number can be ported to another
> operator who will help you with the process.*

So you could say:

> The online forms are processed on a centralized platform without any **transcoding**.
>
> The online forms are processed on a centralized platform without any **porting**.

Both of these are somewhat jargonistic, and in casual speech or writing you might instead consider are **transcription**, **transferal** (**transferral** in BrEng), **re-encoding**, **interpretation** or **reinterpretation**.

Other solutions would be to use a phrase instead of a word, such as **requiring any change of media**, **transferal to another media**, **the need to export it to external formats** etc.

However, you could instead change the sentence to remove the negative:

> The online forms are stored, processed and reviewed end-to-end on a single, centralized platform. We use custom and bespoke file formats throughout, to ensure the highest quality vendor lock-in.

OK, maybe skip the second sentence, it's a bit *too* honest... but that seems to be closer to the intent of the sentence: to say that handling of the form does not require converting it to PDF, sending it via email, and other such hoop-jumping.